# How do I position a Bootstrap card underneath another card with scrollable content?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My web page has two cards: one underneath the other. The top card has scrollable body that contains a large number of input groups. I want the bottom card to be inserted right underneath the top card.

The problem I am getting is that the bottom card is placed far at the bottom of the page as if the layout is taking into account the space occupied by the input groups of the top card, but these should be hidden inside the scrollable section.

The code below shows my setup.

Cheers.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Scrollable Cards</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card text-center col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12" style="height: 45%;">
        <div class="card-header"> Card 1</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="scrollable" style="max-height: 35%; overflow-y: auto;">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text" id="basicaddon1">@</span> </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="normal sized input group" aria-describedby="basicaddon1">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text" id="basicaddon1">@</span> </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="normal sized input group" aria-describedby="basicaddon1">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text" id="basicaddon1">@</span> </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="normal sized input group" aria-describedby="basicaddon1">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text" id="basicaddon1">@</span> </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="normal sized input group" aria-describedby="basicaddon1">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text" id="basicaddon1">@</span> </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="normal sized input group" aria-describedby="basicaddon1">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text" id="basicaddon1">@</span> </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="normal sized input group" aria-describedby="basicaddon1">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card text-center col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12" style="height: 45%;">
        <div class="card-header"> Card 2 </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="scrollable" style="max-height: 35%; overflow-y: auto;">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text" id="basicaddon1">@</span> </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="normal sized input group" aria-describedby="basicaddon1">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text" id="basicaddon1">@</span> </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="normal sized input group" aria-describedby="basicaddon1">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `z-index` of the elements in question?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make some `height` with fix size in px.

For example, **remove** `style="height: 45%;"`, **replace** `style="max-height: 35%; overflow-y: auto;"` with `style="max-height: 150px; overflow-y: auto;"`

And in general your code is pretty messy.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Scrollable Cards</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card text-center col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="card-header"> Card 1</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="scrollable" style="max-height: 150px; overflow-y: auto;">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text" id="basicaddon1">@</span> </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="normal sized input group" aria-describedby="basicaddon1">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text" id="basicaddon1">@</span> </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="normal sized input group" aria-describedby="basicaddon1">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text" id="basicaddon1">@</span> </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="normal sized input group" aria-describedby="basicaddon1">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text" id="basicaddon1">@</span> </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="normal sized input group" aria-describedby="basicaddon1">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text" id="basicaddon1">@</span> </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="normal sized input group" aria-describedby="basicaddon1">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text" id="basicaddon1">@</span> </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="normal sized input group" aria-describedby="basicaddon1">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card text-center col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12" style="height: 45%;">
        <div class="card-header"> Card 2 </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="scrollable" style="max-height: 35%; overflow-y: auto;">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text" id="basicaddon1">@</span> </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="normal sized input group" aria-describedby="basicaddon1">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text" id="basicaddon1">@</span> </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="normal sized input group" aria-describedby="basicaddon1">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```